# Where can I find the code or Recent Posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display the title and description of the recent posts in a customized page. I found some widgets such as Recent Posts but this widget was displayed on specific places such as footer. However I didn't find how this widget works and where I find the source code of this widget? How can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [insert Php](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/), it allows to add php code to html page in wordpress.

Comment: how can I use it?

Comment: You have to add this plugin to your template and then, in your page you add `[insert_php] your code [/insert_php]` and you can get the php program displayed in the html page.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
// Define our WP Query Parameters
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>

// Start our WP Query
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

// Display the Post Title with Hyperlink
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

// Display the Post Excerpt
<li><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></li>

// Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit
<?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

use this code.

Comment: I can't use php code in a html page in wordpress :/

Comment: is it wordpress.com blog ?

Comment: @RyanAW yes it is

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: ask google what's the different wordpress.com vs wordpress self hosted